# Complex summing in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I'm working with a relational database that uses SQL99.

I have a series of 10 columns, each of the 10 columns contain a number value.

I need to sum each column individually and then take those sums and add them all together to get an overall sum. Then I must divide the overall sum by 15.

I've tried every format I can think of and have yet to return any results. I have no idea what the syntax should look like.

Comment: You only want one row returned? Multiple rows, grouped by ___ ?

Comment: But what is the RDBMS, specifically?

Comment: sorry its an Oracle system and all I need to see is the result of the overall sum/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(subsum) / 15 FROM (
   SELECT SUM(column1) AS subsum
      FROM table
     UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(column2) AS subsum
      FROM table
     UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT SUM(column10) AS subsum
      FROM table
)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT SUM(col1), SUM(col2)..., SUM(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4...)/15
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY 1=1
```

Comment: Nice ... better than my version!

Comment: Beware of NULLs, put in a couple of COALESC()s or IFNULL()s

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
      sum(col1) as sum1, 
      sum(col2) as sum2, 
      sum(col3) as sum3, 
      sum(col4) as sum4,
      sum(col5) as sum5, 
      sum(col6) as sum6, 
      sum(col7) as sum7, 
      sum(col8) as sum8,
      sum(col9) as sum9, 
      sum(col10) as as sum10,
      sum( col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8 + col9 + col10) as overallsum,
      sum( col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8 + col9 + col10) / 15 as dividedsum
   from 
      tablename
```